# Door Open with a key in unity C#

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

There is a little game i am working on i want to make a key that opens(Destroy) the door if you have the key, but it doesn't work.

```
void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll) {
      if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Key") {
         Door1 = "Open";
         Destroy(coll.gameObject);
      }

      if (coll.gameObject.tag == "Door") {
         if (Door1 == "Open") {
            Destroy(coll.gameObject);
         }
      }
   }
```

Comment: you can check if `OnCollisionEnter` runs with a DebugLog to check if thats the problem

Comment: Welcome to SO! *it doesn't work* is not a useful problem description.  What's the result of your debugging efforts? Please read [ask and then edit your question to add more information.

Comment: I meant [ask], it's a useful guide for beginners.

Comment: I would also advise you to use ```coll.gameObject.CompareTag()```. which checks if the Tag exists in your scene. This helps to circumvent misspellings.

Comment: Why is `Door1` a string and not a `bool` ? [Debug your code](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/ManagedCodeDebugging.html) and see what goes wrong

Answer (score -1):

Could it be something like this?

```
    public bool doorOpen = false;

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll)
{
    
    if (coll.gameObject.CompareTag("Key"))
    {
        doorOpen = true;
        Debug.Log("The door is now open");
    }
    else
    {
        Destroy(coll.gameObject);
    }
}
```

}